# How to execute a custom script when Internet reconnects?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, internet

My Internet gets disconnected every now and then. I'd like to run a Bash script every time the Internet reconnects.

The script is quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer /home/user/sound.mp3
```

It's placed in `/usr/bin` and works perfectly when I call it as `online_notifier` in Terminal.

I would like to execute this script whenever the Internet reconnects. I tried adding the following line to my `/etc/network/interfaces/` file:

```
post-up sound_notifier
```

This is the full content of that file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
post-up sound_notifier
```

I also tried with the full path as well. But it didn't work. Here's my [`ifconfig` output](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/WKb5n3sFoMmcVNPpLmbX/), if that helps.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are the output of `grep '^plugins' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`  and `grep -A1 '^\[ifupdown\]' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: @heemayl: http://pastie.org/10265816

Comment: Those are two different commands actually..anyway i have got the first one, whats the output of `grep -A1 '^\[ifupdown\]' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: @heemayl: Oops. Sorry about that. The output is: `managed=false`.

Comment: Ok..changed `managed=false` to `managed=true` and then run your script from `/etc/network/interfaces` file or from `/etc/network/ifup.d` directory..

Comment: @heemayl: Before I go ahead and make that change, would you mind explaining what does it do?

Comment: `managed=true` means the `ifupdown` scripts will be managed by `network-manager`..don't worry it won't harm you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple bash script. Make it executable with `chmod +x` and add as custom startup application to run this continuously on every login. Since I've mentioned aplay, this should work in command line, not just gui. My current laptop doesn't have sound,so i had to test everything with `notify-send` . Feel free to adapt the script as necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x

while [ 1 ]; do
  STATUS_CURRENT=$(nmcli -t -f STATE nm status)
  if [[ $STATUS_CURRENT == "connected"  &&  $STATUS_LAST != "connected" ]]; then
        # replace this with aplay sound
        notify-send "We've connected"

# elif [[ $STATUS_CURRENT == "disconnected"  &&  $STATUS_LAST == "connected"  ]];then
#       notify-send "Disconnected now"
  fi

   STATUS_LAST="$STATUS_CURRENT"
   sleep 2
done
```

Comment: This works! But `nmcli -t -f STATE nm status` returning `connected` doesn't necessarily mean that there's Internet connectivity, does it?

Comment: I've replaced that with ``ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo connected || echo disconnected`` - it works fine, but except there's one minor issue. `ip r` does not seem to be returning any output when there's no internet connectivity.

Comment: I think you can shorten `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` part to `ip r | awk '/default/ {print $3}'` . Also, you're just pinging the router, basically, so that's also not the ideal way to test internet connectivity. What if the router has an issue - you connect to it but router doesn't connect to internets ? Pinging external hosts, like 8.8.8.8 is far better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your script has the name `sound_notifier` and it's placed in `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/sound_notifier
```

Create a script `/etc/network/if-up.d/start_sound_notifier`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/start_sound_notifier
```

add the code below

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$METHOD" = loopback ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Only run from ifup.
# if [ "$MODE" != start ]; then
#    exit 0
# fi

sound_notifier
```

Make the script executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/start_sound_notifier
```

That's all

**;)**

Comment: I tried disconnecting and reconnecting. It doesn't work. Grepping `/var/log/syslog` shows this: `Jun 27 23:52:38 networkname nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.`

Comment: @JosephJohn Only a typo in my script and don't forget to set the executable bit for `/usr/bin/sound_notifier`

Comment: Yes, I'd fixed that typo already. But it's still the same. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting, the script does not get executed.

Comment: My MP3 plays after a reconnect. :\

Comment: Mine doesn't - I have no clue as to why.

Comment: The logfiles don't show anything related either.

Comment: Just a thought: wouldn't it be better to have a script that plays a sound when it *dis*connects?  Then you can act upon that....